# "The Departments of Mathematics and Economics". Make sense?

Tags: abbreviations

I wish to list several academic departments in one essay. Initially, I wrote them in full as "the Department of Mathematics, the Department of Economics, the Department of Philosophy". However, it is long and seems verbose. Can I just abbreviate them as "the Departments of Mathematics, Economics, and Philosophy". Does this abbreviation make sense?

Comment: Yes, but I think "departments" should be lower case.

Comment: @DaniilAgashiyev Why is that?

Comment: My sense is that when you list them as such, "departments" ceases to be a part of a proper noun and shouldn't be capitalized. I could be wrong, of course.

Comment: To ensure minimum possibility of confusion, I suggest you write " "the departments of Mathematics, of Economics, and of Philosophy". The 'of' is a clear marker of the boundary between one department and the next. Without it, it is conceivable that someone could perversely infer the existence of the Department of Economics and Philosophy.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can use the plural to "span" several singular items in this way..